# How do I create a persistent Fedora live usb

Tags: live-usb, persistence, fedora

I have successfully created a live USB for Fedora 20 on my Ubuntu 12.04 using `dd`:

```
sudo dd bs=8M if=Fedora-Live-Desktop-x86_64-20-1.iso of=/dev/sdb
```

But I have not been able to find out how to make it persistent. Any suggestions?

Startup Disk Creator is not an option because I am unable to select an ISO file.

Unetbootin failed when I added 512 MBs that should persist and also without it. (2 GB usb stick)

```
Warning: Could not boot
Warning: /dev/disk/by-label/Fedora-Live-Desktop-x86_64-20-1 does not exist
Warning: /dev/mapper/live-rw does not exist
```

Resulting logs: [rdsosreport](http://justpaste.it/f9xt), [journalctl](http://justpaste.it/f9xw)

Comment: Use Unetbootin from the Ubuntu Software Center. Instructions for using UNetbootin with persistence are at [this answer](http://askubuntu.com/questions/350283/help-linux-beginner-how-do-i-put-ubuntu-on-usb-and-boot-install-on-a-pc-with-b/350315#350315).

Comment: To the 2 close voters: are you sure? The iso being fedora does not make this off topic per se ;)

Comment: Yes, the dd command above is good. However, using iostat, you can see that the writing continues after dd terminates from filesys buffers. Follow up with a sync or two and make sure the transfer is done before removing the USB flash drive.

Comment: Check that you know which is the correct target device by using the Disks utility on Ubuntu

Comment: @rleir the person uses an unsupported Ubuntu version and it is not a question to upgrade.

Comment: @MerlijnSebrechts This question was asked in 2014. 12.04 was supported back then. So, it's not off-topic.

Comment: Making a persistent live drive is more complicated than to make a live (live-only) drive, and the method is specific for each linux distro. So I recommend that you search for methods for Fedora at a Fedora web site.

Answer (score 0):

Ubuntu comes with default Disk/Usb creator. Search in Unity `Startup Disk Creater` & after selecting ISO & Drive, select `Stored in reserved extra space` & give your persistence space

OR ELSE

Use [Unetbootin](http://apt.ubuntu.com/p/unetbootin) to make Live USB with persistence!

Comment: I noticed this yes, but both applications state that this works only for Ubuntu. Or is this not true?

Comment: Moreover I can't even select the ISO file in the Startup Disk Creator.

Comment: check Unetbootin site, it specifies clearly Fedora 17-20 & many other distros

Comment: It states that maintaining files across reboots (i.e. persistence) is only available for Ubuntu. But I am trying now. Will let you know if it works.