# My Dell Laptop with Ubuntu is not booting

Tags: boot, usb, flash

I don't have boot DVD/flash drive. I have a desk top with XP SP3; I have downloaded a USB installer to make boot USB but net Ubuntu ISO. How to download this ISO file and make the boot USB?

Comment: You can get the ISO file from [Ubuntu](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop) website and use [UNetbootin](http://sourceforge.net/projects/unetbootin/) *or the one you have already downloaded) to create bootable USB using the ISO file you have downloaded. Refer [this](http://www.makeuseof.com/tag/install-linux-with-ease-using-unetbootin/) guide on how to use UNetbootin

Comment: possible duplicate of [Help, linux beginner! How do I put ubuntu on usb and boot/install on a PC with blank harddrive?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/350283/help-linux-beginner-how-do-i-put-ubuntu-on-usb-and-boot-install-on-a-pc-with-b)

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I install Ubuntu from an USB drive / create a live USB-stick in Windows?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/26269/how-do-i-install-ubuntu-from-an-usb-drive-create-a-live-usb-stick-in-windows)

Answer (score 0):

well first, you need to go to ubuntu.com and download ubuntu, 32 or 64 bit (based on your computer age), then download the universal usb installer from pendrivelinux.com.  then run the application and browse for the .iso file,for example, ubuntu14.10desktop.ISO or something like that. then install to flash drive. after finished,

1: turn off computer

2: plug usb into desired*emphasized text* computer

3: power up while repeatedly pressing f12 or f2 so you can get to boot from the usb device.

4: IMPORTANT: if you want a dual boot computer, then carefully in the partition editor make a place for the OS that varies from 10- whatever amount of storage you need

then install updates when finished with installing everything.

reply if you need any other help.