# Tests to check hardware before buying a notebook?

Tags: laptop, compatibility

I have the possibility of using a live USB with Ubuntu before buying a notebook.

What are some **quick tests** I can run to make sure the notebook is **compatible with Ubuntu** and there are no problems?

Should I also run commands like `lshw`?

---

Okay, so I will:

- check the functionality of extra keys
- then I'll try to connect to a WiFi
- sleeping and waking up
- all the USB ports

Should I also run commands like ***lshw***?

Comment: The only test that matters is the real world usage. But in a live session you can check whether or not all hardware is being recognized.

Comment: There is a "system testing" option in "dash".

Answer (score 5):

You can test if a computer's hardware is compatible with Ubuntu by downloading the [Ubuntu Live DVD](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/LiveCD) iso file and booting the [live DVD](https://askubuntu.com/questions/307742/how-to-burn-an-iso-image-into-a-dvd-on-ubuntu/828879#828879) or [live USB](https://askubuntu.com/questions/350283/help-linux-beginner-how-do-i-put-ubuntu-on-usb-and-boot-install-on-a-pc-with-b/350315#350315). The Ubuntu live USB runs faster than the live DVD and has the additional advantage of being reusable for something else after you are finished testing and/or installing Ubuntu with it.

A live DVD/USB can be used for a quick demo or test of Ubuntu to check if the computer's hardware works as expected without making any changes to the machine. Windows or whatever is already installed on the computer is unaffected after trying this and then rebooting. See [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/951365/best-way-to-create-a-bootable-usb-volume-for-testing-potential-pc-purchases-for/951380#951380) for detailed and specific information about how to create a bootable USB flash drive for testing potential PC purchases for compatibility with Ubuntu.

Many computer stores provide their own Ubuntu live USB with Ubuntu for testing Ubuntu as a service to their customers. I discovered this after trying to return a graphics card that wouldn't boot Ubuntu, when a technician plugged the graphics card into one of the store's computers and booted Ubuntu from that computer to show me that my new graphics card was compatible with Ubuntu. If the computer store won't let you test their laptop with your Ubuntu live media, ask if they have their own USB with Ubuntu, and will demonstrate Ubuntu with it on the computer of your choice.

A quick demo can test two things:

1. Check if hardware (Ethernet, USB, sound, webcam) works as expected.
2. Check the look and feel of the operating system.

Wifi cannot always be tested with a quick demo. Even if the laptop doesn't connect to wifi in the store, it might still work after installing the driver for the wireless adapter.

Comment: Yea, I went to a store and asked a retail guy if it's possible to test another OS before buying the laptop. He said it's allowed and he even had a USB with Ubuntu.

Answer (score 1):

If the notebook is absolutely incompatible with Ubuntu (unlikely as long as you are not buying a model which has just recently been released) you will notice, because you live system will not work at all, i.e. the graphics system won't be able to display, because of missing drivers etc.

A common issue are "multimedia keys", they are usually on the top of they keyboard and you need to press an extra key like "fn" to activate them (you know, key for making audio louder or make the screen brighter). You should definitely test those.

I would also test some energy funtionalities, just active the standby mode or close the notebook and then see if the system is able to awake from sleeping mode.

A little research on the internet to see if people allready made experiences with that notebook and Ubuntu doesn't hurt.

Comment: After graphics, the biggest problem is with WIFi.  Check to make sure you can see SSIDs pop up in the networking indicator at the very least.

Comment: @StephenM.Webb also things like Ethernet, USB, webcam...