# Has anyone tried installing Ubuntu (or any linux distro) on an Eluktronics (N850HK1) laptop?

Tags: laptop

I'm about to buy this [Eluktronics laptop](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B06X6CG5TF) and just want to make sure it will run well on it. I'm guessing that gaming laptops usually expect to have Windows installed and so it may not be suitable for Linux. Can anyone give me some insight? Anyone used this laptop with Ubuntu or any other distro? I see that Eluktronics isn't certified but I ***really*** like the specs it has for the price.

Any advice?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is a shopping question.

Comment: But it's not a shopping recommendation request. I think this is answerable, and answers can be durable and finite. Voting to Leave Open.

Comment: It falls under the category of __too close__, specific to very few people. Ask Ubuntu is not suitable for these cases.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Tests to check hardware before buying a notebook?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/836462/tests-to-check-hardware-before-buying-a-notebook)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So I bought it, installed Ubuntu. Everything ran pretty smoothly as far as installation goes but there are a few problems such as brightness keys not working, but nothing that can't be worked around. Haven't has any issues with random hanging during shutdown, sleep, etc. So an in all, this laptop is pretty compatible with Ubuntu!

EDIT: After a bit more use, there's a lot of problems. It's usable but just little annoying things like you can't change the color of keyboard (which may or may not be the cause of it heating so fast), the brightness keys do not work and all work-arounds I've tried have not fixed them, cinnamon battery applet does not update, and there's not much documentation on the fixes for these so they're just little annoying things you have to deal with.

Comment: Use this, should help you resolve most of your issues: https://gist.github.com/Brainiarc7/f7da590bee1ed35ac5ed258ff9335fd6