# Installing Ubuntu on a blank machine

Tags: 14.04, usb

I'm getting a new PC next month and let's face it I'n mot paying all that money for Windows to have it taken off straight away fro 14.04, so I opted for No OS.

I have a USB stick with Ubuntu 14.04 on it (created by using Lili live Linux USB creator), if I plug this into the port, will it boot from the USB?

Any help is appreciated, thanks in advance ! :D

Comment: It should work - have you checked for to see if the computer is compatible with Ubuntu?

Comment: It's a custom PC (from CyberPower) and the specs are about a million times better than my lappy (which isn't on the Ubuntu list of certified hardware)

Comment: Forgot to mention my lappy is running 14.04

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I install Ubuntu?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/6328/how-do-i-install-ubuntu) or [How do I install Ubuntu on a computer without an OS on it?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/231719/how-do-i-install-ubuntu-on-a-computer-without-an-os-on-it)

Comment: @EliahKagan May I ask how is it a duplicate? The accpeted answer refers to a system which already has an OS on the machine.

Comment: @TreyTaylor I've added [another link](http://askubuntu.com/questions/231719/how-do-i-install-ubuntu-on-a-computer-without-an-os-on-it) that is more specific (or you can use the other answers besides the accepted one).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you have no OS, it should boot right away as long as you created the USB correctly and your computer supports boot from USB (most do these days).

If it doesn't work right away, go to your BIOS settings by pressing the appropriate key at startup (this varies from machine to machine, usually one of the function keys, sometimes the boot screen will tell you what to press. a google search should give you what you need).

Once in the BIOS settings, look for the boot options, and you should see a list of the different boot media your computer supports (probably at least CD, USB, and however many hard drives you have). Just make sure boot from USB is enabled and ordered above any other media that have an OS on it (e.g. if you had another OS installed already on the hard drive, make sure USB has priority over the hard drive).