# No root partition

Tags: root, partitioning

I'm having serious problems trying to install ubuntu 14.04 on my Toshiba Satellite C850 laptop. Whenever I try to install it it says "No root file system found. Please correct this error from the partitioning menu." I've tried to create new partitions but I don't know what size to make them etc. can someone please help me on this? (Is there a way to create partitions through the terminal? I'm new to ubuntu) but i was on it 2 days ago, laptops crashed and now I can't get past the installation. I've created a new  partitioning table just need guidance on which partitions to create and how big to make them. I have absolutely no partitions whatsoever on my hard drive (or whatever the partitions are part of) so it will need to be from the very start. Thanks in advance!

Comment: You might prefer to have Ubuntu's installer partition for you, instead of doing it manually. Either way, see [How do I install Ubuntu?](http://askubuntu.com/q/6328/22949), [How do I install Ubuntu on a computer without an OS on it?](http://askubuntu.com/q/231719/22949), and [How to use manual partitioning during installation?](http://askubuntu.com/q/343268/22949)

Answer (score -1):

You only need 2 partitions, make a swap partiton of about 3 GB and make the rest of the space formatted as ext4 and mounted as /.

This is the simpelist way to set it up.

First delete anything on the disk make it all empty space.

Then make a new partition and set format to swap and size to 3000 and accept this.

Now make another new partition and set format to ext4, mount point to / and type to primary. Dont change the size.

Now apply these settings and install

Comment: I will improve the answers detail for you please tell me the size of you hard drive

Comment: The size if my hard drive is 320GB

Answer (score -1):

I recommend you to create the partitions throughout the installation process (but you could use something like GParted Live too). Just choose the 'Something else' option when you have to choose where you want your operating system to be installed and then select the 'New partition' option.
I think you have an EFI BIOS so you need a `/boot/efi` partition as well.

If you want to have a Linux only system:

1. 200MB partition primary, mount point: /boot/efi
2. 15GB partition primary, ext4 file system, mount point: /
3. 308.024 MB logical partition, ext4 file system, mount point: /home
4. partition primary 4096 MB used as swap

P.S.: Set a flag to format them.